# Detect objects position (right, left) on a image using PHP and Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have some scripts in PHP and Imagick (ImageMagick) to trim background image, fill with a solid color and resize, but I need to flip images depending of image contents.

All images must have all contents on the left, then I need to analyze image and detect if most of contents are on right or left, and if contents are detected on right, I need to flip (I have the code to flip image).

For example:

Valid Image. Most part of image obects/lines/contents are on left.

[image: Valid Image]

Invalid Image. Most part of image obects/lines/contents are on right, must be flipped.

[image]

There are any way to detect this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My final script:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @param string $image
 * @param string $side
 *
 * @return \Imagick
 */
function flop(string $image, string $side): Imagick
{
    $image = new Imagick($image);

    $clone = clone($image);
    $clone->resizeImage(200, 200, Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1, true);
    $clone->modulateImage(100, 0, 100);

    $w = $clone->getImageWidth();
    $h = $clone->getImageHeight();

    $wHalf = $w / 2;
    $right = $left = 0;

    for ($x = 0; $x < $w; ++$x) {
        for ($y = 0; $y < $h; ++$y) {
            if ($clone->getImagePixelColor($x, $y)->getColorAsString() === 'srgb(255,255,255)') {
                continue;
            }

            if ($x > $wHalf) {
                ++$right;
            } else {
                ++$left;
            }
        }
    }

    if (($side === 'left') && ($right > $left)) {
        $image->flopImage();
    } elseif (($side === 'right') && ($left > $right)) {
        $image->flopImage();
    }

    return $image;
}
```